# Integrating a sum of delta functions?

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, laplacian, greens-function

I know that the "hand-wavy" definition of the $\delta (x)$ function is
$$  
\delta(x) = 
     \begin{cases}
       \infty &\quad\ x=0 \\
       0 &\quad\text{otherwise}
     \end{cases}
$$

and the more rigorous definition is that it's the **limit** of a sequence of functions $f_n$ for which $f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ for all $x \neq 0$, and $f_n \rightarrow \infty$ for $x=0$, and (edited to add) $\int f_n = 1$ for all $n$. From this perspective, I see why the integral should be one, because the integral of all of the $f_n$ is equal to $1$.

Now, suppose I want to construct a function $f(x,y)$ in the plane for which

$$  
\nabla ^2f(x,y) = 
     \begin{cases}
       a &\quad\ (x,y) \in D \\
       0 &\quad\text{otherwise}
     \end{cases}
$$
where $D$ is some simply connected region.

I can definitely solve $\nabla ^2f(x,y) = \delta(\|(x,y) - (x_0,y_0)\|)$ for any point $(x_0,y_0)$. This is just done by using the fundamental solution $$f(x,y) = \frac{-1}{2\pi} \ln\left( \|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)\|\right)$$

My question is whether I can do the following:

Because I want the Laplacian of $f$ to be as described above, can I write

$$ f(x,y) = a \int_D \frac{-1}{2\pi} \ln\left( \|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)\|\right) \,dA \quad ?$$

where $dA$ refers to integration with respect to $(x_0,y_0)$ over the area of $D$.

My confusion is coming from the fact that: The Laplacian of $f$ will be the Laplacian of a sum of (infinitely) many $\delta$ functions, so intuition tells me it should be infinite; on the other hand, integrating a $\delta$ function gives $1$, so the factor of $a$ in front of the integral should give the desired result, no?

Comment: Your "more rigorous" definition is still pretty hand-wavy. You may say that $\delta$ is the limit of a certain kind of sequence of functions, but if you multiply all of those functions by $3$ then you get another sequence of the same kind, but it doesn't converge to $\delta$, but rather to $3\delta$, and that's different since $$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) \Big( 3\delta(x)\Big)\, dx = 3g(0) \ne g(0). $$

Comment: @MichaelHardy He did mention the integral of each $f_n$ is $1$.

Comment: @Paichu : ok. But still there's the issue of what happens if you use one sequence of functions meeting the desiderata and I use another such sequence.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I agree that the rigorous definition is still not very rigorous.

Answer (score 0):

You should solve Laplace's equation using a Fourier transform.  You can write the **actual** Delta function as

$$\delta(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\!e^{-ikx}\,dk$$

Further, when you Fourier transform the Laplace equation you get

$$\mathcal{F}[\nabla^2f(x,y)]=-k^2\hat{f}(x,y)$$

If you solve the problem in $k$-space for $\hat{f}(x,y)$ and then perform a reverse Fourier transform, you will have your solution.

To be clear:  Laplace's equation is NOT solved by integrating a sum of delta functions.

Comment: For a similar problem, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334325/fourier-transform-of-laplace-equation-with-boundary-conditions

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a solution to your equation. This is an instance of a more general method: convolving with the fundamental solution ([see e.g. the Wikipedia article about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_solution#Motivation)).

**Notes about notation:** single $x$ denotes a point $(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $dx$ denotes integration over a domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\Delta$ is the Laplace operator (so that it's not confused with the hessian),

**How it's applied.**
Let $g$ be the fundamental solution, meaning that $\Delta g = \delta$ (in our case, $g(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \ln|x|$). and $h$ is an integrable function, then
$$
f(x) := \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} g(x-y)h(y) \, dy
\qquad \text{(often denoted as $(g * h)(x)$)}
$$
solves $\Delta f = h$ in a weak sense. If $h$ has better regularity, then $f$ is also a classical solution (a $C^2$ function with $\Delta f = h$ pointwise). If you take $h$ to be $a \cdot \mathbf{1}_{D}$ (the function equal $a$ in $D$ and $0$ elsewhere), then $f$ is exactly the function you described: $f(x) = \int_D g(x-y) \, dy$. On the other hand, $\Delta f = \mathbf{1}_{D}$ is the equation you wanted to solve

**How it works.**
Since this topic (solving the Poisson equation by convolving with the fundamental solution) is covered in many places, let me just direct you to L. Evans's *Partial Differential Equations*. One word of caution: in our example the function $h$ is not continuous and so $f$ cannot possibly have $C^2$ regularity. For that reason, one should aim for the *weak sense* of $\Delta f = h$, which is even easier to prove than the classical case, if only one already knows what *weak* means. Again, Evans gives a nice account of weak solutions.